# What is the difference between test labels and validation labels in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, train-test-split, test-data

I have a question with regards to the training and validation of a dataset.

I understand the concept of labels for training data i.e. y_train. What I don't get is that why should our testing/validation samples have labels as well.
I assume that by giving labels to the test samples, we define what they are before putting them through the algorithm right?

Let me put it this way, if I have a dataset of pictures of dogs and cats, and I label them 1 and 2, respectively. Then if I want to throw a picture (dog) to test my model, which was not in my training dataset, why should I label it? If I label it 1, then I'm telling beforehand that it's a dog and if I label it 2, then it is a cat already.

Can I have a testing/validation dataset without label?

Comment: The question is a general ML one, and not related to specific languages & frameworks (`python`, `keras`, `tensorflow`) - related tags were removed.

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it (otherwise please leave feedback) - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation dataset is used to finetune the parameters in your model while the test set is used to check the accuracy. Without the label how can claim the correctness of your model. This concept is valid in supervised learning so one needs to have labels with testing and validation dataset.

Comment: Are you saying that from testing I have to put a data without label?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are saying

Comment: In order to measure the performance you need labels in test set . For qualitative results which doesn't measure performance one can use data points without labels

Comment: Please upvote if you are satisfied with my result.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a *test* set is, as its name implies, to test the performance of your model in data that were not seen during training. And in order to get this performance indication, you certainly need data with known labels, in order to *compare* these labels (ground truth) with the corresponding model predictions, and to arrive to some *quantitative* measure (e.g. accuracy) of your model performance - something you can certainly *not* do without these labels being available in the test set.

> if I want to throw a picture (dog) to test my model, why should I label it? If I label it 1, then I'm telling beforehand that it's a dog and if I label it 2, then it is a cat already.

You are using the term "test" very loosely here - this is not its meaning in the context of a test set (which context I just described above). Notice also that, the fact that the test labels are available, does not mean that they are being *used* by the model during prediction (they are certainly not - they are only used for *comparison* with the model predictions, as described above). Plus, you are referring to a very specific problem where the answer (cat/dog) is obvious to a human observer - try using the same rationale e.g. in a genomics problem, or in one that requests numeric predictions for, say, house prices, and you'll see that the situation is not *that* simple and straightforward (could you possibly name the price of a house by just looking at *a row of numbers*?)...

The same applies for a validation set, only the objective here is different (i.e. not model assessment, but model tuning).

Admittedly, some people use the term "test data" to mean in general any *unseen* data, but this is not correct; after you have build & assess your model using your training, validation, and test sets, you deploy it feeding it with new and obviously unseen data, for which it is certainly *not* expected to already know the labels...

There are literally dozens of online tutorials on the subject, and SO is arguably not the most appropriate forum for this kind of questions - I just hope I have given you a first good-enough general idea...