# Can we test the Naive Bayes algorithm with unlabeled data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have trained the model using labeled data for Naive Bayes algorithm. And tested the same model with the other set of labeled data. And I have calculated accuracy, precision and recall scores using the below code.

## My code :

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from io import open

def load_data(filename):
    reviews = list()
    labels = list()
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().split(' ',1)
            labels.append(line[0])
            reviews.append(line[1])

    return reviews, labels


X_train, y_train = load_data('./train_data.txt')
X_test, y_test = load_data('./test_data.txt')

vec = CountVectorizer() 

X_train_transformed =  vec.fit_transform(X_train) 

X_test_transformed = vec.transform(X_test)

clf= MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train)

score = clf.score(X_test_transformed, y_test)
print("score of Naive Bayes algo is :" , score)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_transformed)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))

print("Precision Score : ",precision_score(y_test, y_pred,average='micro'))
print("Recall Score : ",recall_score(y_test, y_pred,average='micro'))
```

But, now I have another test set which contains unlabeled data. Now, can I test the model with this unlabeled data using the above code ?

Comment: By "unsupervised" data I take it that you actually mean *unlabeled*, right?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you mean by "test the model"; my answer here may be of help for clarifying things & concepts: [Confusion about test & validation set labels in machine learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423386/confusion-about-test-validation-set-labels-in-machine-learning/52423685#52423685)

Comment: yes.. "unsupervised" mean the "unlabeled" data

Comment: Edited & updated your question, but a better familiarity with the relevant terminology is strongly advised. Still waiting for clarification regarding what kind of testing you mean (and if possibly the linked answer has helped)...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could interpret from your question.

You have trained `Naive Bayes` model use train data & tested it using test data and you have used `confusion matrix & accuracy` as a metric to measure the performance of the model.

Now your question may be

> Using this model, is it possible to predict label of the unseen data which don't have any labels ?

if that is your question, then, YES it is possible. Moreover that is the reason why you have trained the model i.e, to predict the labels on unseen data.

Since the unseen data don't have labels, how do you know predicted labels are correct ? For this reason only you have tested the model with `test data` & measured the performance of the model. If the accuracy of the model is `70%`, then 70% of the times your model is predicting correctly.

I strongly suggest you to think `why are you doing what are you doing` before start doing it!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically calculate the accuracy of the model with unseen data then answer is NO.

To create confusion matix and find out these matrices you need to pass Y label variable. Good practice is to split your training data into training and test data.